# Just lost 2 rep on a community wiki down vote

Tags: support, community-wiki

Have the community wiki rules changed recently?

I just lost 2 points on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/112920/whats-your-favorite-abandoned-rule/113371#113371) answer. I'm not that fussed over the 2 points, I'm just surprised a CW vote can, apparently, gain or lose votes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The whole question and all answers appear to have been turned into community wiki 6 hours ago.  Chances are good you got that downvote (and lost the 2 rep) before it turned into a CW post.

Comment: You're right - "Post Made Community Wiki by Bill the Lizard♦
occurred 3 hours ago" http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/113371/list